# Python For OpenCV2.4

Tags: python, opencv

I downloaded opencv 2.4 source code from svn, and then I used the command 'cmake -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF' to generate makefile and make and install. I found that the python module was successfully made. But when I import cv2 in python, no module cv2 exists. Is there anything else I should configure? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either copy the cv2 library to a location in your PYTHONPATH or add your current directory to the PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run 'make install' or 'sudo make install'? While not absolutely necessary, it copies the generated binaries to your system paths.